# Incorrectly navigates to classic instead of lightning in Mobile App (LWC) on button click

Tags: lightning-web-components, url, salesforce-mobile-app

Here is the code which I used in LWC code:

```javascript
this.backToCustomObjectURL = "https://test.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/custom_object__c/"+ this.recordId +"/view"

window.open(this.backToCustomObjectURL, "_self")
```